# how ro Plot correctly the mean of means with geom_hlines and yintercept

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, mean

I am trying to create a violin plot using ggplot2 of samples and on top to draw the mean of means. How does ggplot_boxplot calculates the means of the samples and how can I calculate this and have the correct value.

```
set.seed(101)
#create the data frame
cdat <- as.data.frame(matrix(runif(1000),nrow=10))
#create the long table (or how it is called)
mutcdat <- reshape2::melt(t(log(as.matrix(cdat),2)))
#calculate the mean of means
mutline <- mean(rowMeans(log(as.matrix(cdat),2)))
ggplot2::ggplot(mutcdat,aes(x=factor(Var2),y=value, fill = Var2))+
  ggplot2::geom_violin()+
  geom_boxplot(aes(x = factor(Var2), y = value), width = 0.2)+
  ggplot2::guides(fill=guide_legend(title="samples")) +
  ggplot2::geom_hline(aes(yintercept = mutline))
```

[image: the line from geom_hline is lower than expected]

Comment: I do not think that this is correct: the mean of all and the mean of the means is the same. it is matter where the log is placed because the mean of the log2 of the means is different than the log2 of the mean of means.
 
```>mean(rowMeans(as.matrix(data_norm)))
[1] 423898340```
```> mean(unlist(data_norm))
[1] 423898340```
```> mean(rowMeans((as.matrix(cdat))))
[1] 0.4923063```
```> mean(unlist(cdat))
[1] 0.4923063```

Comment: I added another example, using another data set called data_norm

Comment: OK, I dig a bit on the box plot and the ggplot2 geom_boxplot and apparently the function calculates the MEDIAN not the mean